# How to add data to a django admin change_list page taken from a different model?

Tags: django, django-admin, overriding, django-views

I would like to add a bit of information to a certain change_list admin page. The info is taken from a queryset on a different model than that presented in this template. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [Custom Template Tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) - you can fetch and use anything in it.

Answer (score 4):

Try to rewrite `changelist_view` function in your admin class:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # .....
    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra = {'foo': bar}
        extra.update(extra_context or {})
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra)
    # .....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [custom context processor](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/14/django-tips-template-context-processors/). This allows you to expose a variable to the whole application. It works on pages rendered using RequestContext, tried this with the admin pages and it works.